# what does "媒介にして" mean ?

Tags: translation, meaning

when i was reading Rosario+vampire s2  manga i read this sentence
''血液を媒介にしてのみ真祖は継承されるの”

血液＝blood

媒介＝Intermediary

のみ＝Only

真祖＝term in the manga indicates vampires ancestors

継承＝Inheritance

then what does ''媒介にして" mean ? its not ''媒介する” right ?
and is "継承される" the passive form of "継承する” ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`媒介にして` means `as the medium`

```
血液を媒介にしてのみ真祖は継承されるの
```

means

```
use the blood as the medium to become the 真祖
```

it think the sentence means if a `真祖` bites another person or vampire, then the blood of the `真祖` will flow into the person, then he will also become the `真祖`

PS: this is a pretty common setting appears in many ACGs, like [Tsukihime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsukihime), [Tsukuyomi](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=2478)

Comment: first thank you for answering .
yes i think so right after posting the question i realizeｄ　that ”にして”　here mean "by making" so the whole phrase will mean "真祖 inherited only by making the blood as the medium"
in Rosario+vampire context it doesn't mean that 真祖 will  bite but will be bitten